# Way to overcome fail-fast iterator in HashMap

Tags: java, exception, data-structures, collections

In competitive programming, I was solving a given problem - given an array `nums` of non-negative integers, and a target sum `S`, we have to find out the number of ways we can obtain target sum from sum of given numbers (where each `nums[i]` can be taken as `nums[i]` or `-nums[i]`.

Although I came across some solutions that mainly relied on direct access tables using array (it is given that sum of numbers cannot exceed 1000), but I tried it using HashMap to reduce the space required. My code is as follows -

```
    public int findTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> dp = new HashMap();
        dp.put(nums[0], 1);
        dp.put(-nums[0], dp.getOrDefault(-nums[0], 0) + 1);
        
        for (int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
            for (Integer sum : dp.keySet()) {
                dp.put(sum+nums[i], dp.getOrDefault(sum+nums[i], 0) + 1);
                dp.put(sum-nums[i], dp.getOrDefault(sum-nums[i], 0) + 1);
            }
        }
        return dp.get(S);
    }
```

But I am getting ConcurrentModificationException on running the code. I tried finding about the issue. Although I got some conceptual understanding that in iteration, view of Collections can't be structurally modified, I am not able to figure out how to find my way around it to find a solution.

Is it that a solution using HashMap(or any dynamic data structure) is not possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (Integer sum : dp.keySet()) {
  dp.put(sum+nums[i], dp.getOrDefault(sum+nums[i], 0) + 1);
  // ...
}
```

If `sum + nums[i]` isn't a key that's already in the map, this results in a structural modification of the map: that is, you're adding a new key/value pair.

As described [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

(If the key were already in the map, you'd just be modifying the value associated with that key, and this would be fine).

The easiest way to get around this is to take a snapshot of the keys to iterate over, by copying the elements into e.g. a list:

```
for (Integer sum : new ArrayList<>(dp.keySet())) {
```

Now, you're iterating the list, not the map's keyset, so you are free to modifying the map structurally inside that loop.

---

Separately from the question of the exception, your `put/getOrDefault` lines would be more simply written as:

```
// dp.put(sum+nums[i], dp.getOrDefault(sum+nums[i], 0) + 1);
// becomes
dp.merge(sum+nums[i], 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `ConcurrentModificationException` is that you are modifying the keys of `dp` while iterating `dp.keySet()` in the following loop:

```
for (Integer sum : dp.keySet()) {
    dp.put(sum+nums[i], dp.getOrDefault(sum+nums[i], 0) + 1);
    dp.put(sum-nums[i], dp.getOrDefault(sum-nums[i], 0) + 1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

Comment: And I don't even know why you think this is wrong. It looks correct to me: it's saying "the value associated with this key, or zero", because OP is effectively doing a merging count.